# Emacs Lisp edit nested list in place

Tags: list, emacs, buffer, elisp

I have a problem I am trying to solve. I have a list of methods and their buffer positions. I created it with the form

```
 (("method_foo" 588 . 640)
  ("method_bar" 557 . 587)
  ("method_baz" 605 . 630))
```

and so forth. I have a mechanism to get the new positions I need. However I can't seem to find a clean way to update the buffer positions in the list. This seems like a simple thing, especial for a **LIS**t **P**rocessor, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with:

```el
(setq my-alist '(("method_foo" 588 . 640)
                 ("method_bar" 557 . 587)
                 ("method_baz" 605 . 630)))
```

If you wanted to change the positions for `"method_bar"` from `(557 . 587)` to `(60 . 80)`, you could do:

```el
(let ((positions (assoc "method_bar" my-alist)))
  (setf (cadr positions) 60
        (cddr positions) 80))
```

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Setting Generalized Variables` <kbd>RET</kbd> for details on the usage of `setf`

Comment: Please try to explain what your code does. Thus other (future) users can also understand the soulution. As a high-rep user you should know that such posts are labeled as "Low Quality Posts" automatically.

Comment: There just isn't very much to explain here -- and anyone writing elisp knows how to use `C-h f` to learn what each function is doing -- but sure, I'll elaborate a bit...

Comment: Thank you! `setf` was the piece I was missing.